# Use sass as a entry point in webpack?

Tags: webpack

As you can see in the webpack documentation that they have used a js file as an entry point.

[image: entry point in webpack]

I am using a webpack on a small project where js is not used at all, only using HTML and CSS *(SASS)*. So if I use a sass file as an entry point, will the webpack will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [`css-entry-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-entry-webpack-plugin) if it helps, if not, you can define a `js` file that will import your scss, with a combination of Extract-text-plugin you will get a css file.

Create a `js` file that will contain an import to your scss file,

```
// entry.js
import './style.scss';
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but why not to do the `js` thingy?

Comment: I do use `js` file but in big projects, in small project why to use `js` file and then use some extra packages to extract the `CSS` file and then attach the file to `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but i had some what the same problem.

But i could solve the problem with file-loader as described [here](https://florianbrinkmann.com/en/5351/webpack-sass-multiple-entry-points/)

Also note that i use webpack4.

My config file looks like this.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {

let config = {
    entry: [
        path.resolve('./src/js/main.js'),
        path.resolve('./src/scss/style.scss')
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve('./dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].css',
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    watch: (argv.mode == 'development')
}

return config;
```

}